# Operations with unix epoch timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix-timestamp

I need help, well the problem's that  i need to know how I compare one date  with unix epoch timestamp format (a) with actual date (b) in jquery, i need to know if (a) it`s in interval of 3hours to the actual date (b)

Comment: Quite obvious solution, convert the date to timestamp too, and compare them as numbers.

Comment: Can you show us, What have you tried? simply use `new Date(unix epoch timestamp);`

Comment: For ANYTHING date related lean on momentJS it makes this type of task a no brainer http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a unix timestamp (seconds from epoch) is within 3h of another date like so (otherDateB being the date object and epochTimeStampA the epoch timestamp as a number):

```
function withinThreeHours(epochTimeStampA, otherDateB) {
    var aTimeFromBtime = otherDateB - (epochTimeStampA * 1000);
    var threeHours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3;
    return aTimeFromBtime <= threeHours;
}
```

Comment: ahh ok you want to say that my actual date convert to EpochTimeStamp too and then I do the operations! ok ok thanks!!

Comment: You don't actually need to convert the other date manually, when you compare a date to a number, it's automatically coersed to a number (which is the milliseconds from unix epoch).